# WCF: How do you handle the UnknownMessageReceived message?

Tags: wcf

Currently I have this:

```
Private Sub AamServiceHost_UnknownMessageReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs) Handles Me.UnknownMessageReceived

    m_Log.Write(m_Name & " has received an unknown message. The message will be ignored.", Severity.ErrorTaskFailed)

End Sub
```

I see there is a e.Message property but I'm not sure what parts of it are safe to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In General, you can read any part of the message, like it's properties, headers and the contents. Is there a reason, however, you need to handle this event? In general, if this is happening it means either that you're missing something on your contract/service implementation (otherwise, it's useful for debugging, but it's not something you should really rely on).

Comment: Just debugging. It gets triggered when malformed messages are sent to a message queue or an application is pointed to the wrong target.